# Typeid() Check of Passing Paramaters of A Templated Function

Tags: c++, windows, templates, typeid

I don't want to use function overload for a small change in a function. Instead, I want to use typeid() check of passing parameter of the templated function below. But, If I don't comment out the line in the code below, it gives the compile error of:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >')
```

As I understand the compiler does not know how to behave. Is there a solution for this?

The code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
void Test(T A)
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(vector<string>)) {
        cout << "The type of A is vector<string>" << endl << endl;
        //cout << "First element of A is:" << A[0] << endl;    // If I don't comment out this line, it gives the compiler error.
    }

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(vector<vector<string>>)) {
        cout << "The type of A is vector<vector<string>>" << endl;
        cout << "First row first element of A is:" << A[0][0] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Test(vector<string> {"1", "2", "3"});

    Test(vector<vector<string>> { {"11", "12", "13"}, { "21", "22", "23" }});

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in *ordinary* `if`, the *statement-true* (and *statement-false* if present) has to be valid statement at compile-time, no matter what's the result of the *condition*, for every instantiation of `Test` with the type `T` given.

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) since C++17 (with `std::is_same`).

> In a constexpr if statement, the value of *condition* must be a
>   [contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression). If the value
>   is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise,
>   *statement-true* is discarded.

e.g.

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, vector<string>>) {
    cout << "The type of A is vector<string>" << endl << endl;
    cout << "First element of A is:" << A[0] << endl;
} 

if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, vector<vector<string>>>) {
    cout << "The type of A is vector<vector<string>>" << endl;
    cout << "First row first element of A is:" << A[0][0] << endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qoL0hVy5HvR2juLL)

Before C++17 you can go with [SFINAE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/piNwnSX2SpIIBaDb) or [specialization](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mpB58DfA9ahoLYJz) (with templates), or just [overloading](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QHSc6FA00VQ9iUS2) (even without templates).